# Building and formatting date from text

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a JS project where the user takes a picture of any supermarket product expiry date, and the program extracts the date and puts it in a database, so a couple of days before that date the user receives a notification (PWA stuff).
The image gets processed by the google cloud vision algorithm and returns a lot of informations, with the text extracted from the image, for example:

image processed

[image]

[json result](https://pastebin.com/Mwj0VsaC) (code is long, sorry for external redirects)
example:

```js
{
  "responses": [{
    "textAnnotations": [{
        "locale": "it",
        "description": "Da consumarsi preferibilmente entro:\n15 04 11\n",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 48,
              "y": 8
            },
            {
              "x": 249,
              "y": 8
            },
            {
              "x": 249,
              "y": 59
            },
            {
              "x": 48,
              "y": 59
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "Da",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 48,
              "y": 10
            },
            {
              "x": 61,
              "y": 10
            },
            {
              "x": 61,
              "y": 22
            },
            {
              "x": 48,
              "y": 22
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "consumarsi",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 65,
              "y": 10
            },
            {
              "x": 126,
              "y": 10
            },
            {
              "x": 126,
              "y": 21
            },
            {
              "x": 65,
              "y": 21
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "preferibilmente",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 130,
              "y": 9
            },
            {
              "x": 211,
              "y": 9
            },
            {
              "x": 211,
              "y": 23
            },
            {
              "x": 130,
              "y": 23
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "entro:",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 214,
              "y": 8
            },
            {
              "x": 249,
              "y": 8
            },
            {
              "x": 249,
              "y": 23
            },
            {
              "x": 214,
              "y": 23
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "15",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 115,
              "y": 44
            },
            {
              "x": 145,
              "y": 44
            },
            {
              "x": 145,
              "y": 58
            },
            {
              "x": 115,
              "y": 58
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "04",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 162,
              "y": 46
            },
            {
              "x": 195,
              "y": 46
            },
            {
              "x": 195,
              "y": 59
            },
            {
              "x": 162,
              "y": 59
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "description": "11",
        "boundingPoly": {
          "vertices": [{
              "x": 212,
              "y": 46
            },
            {
              "x": 238,
              "y": 46
            },
            {
              "x": 238,
              "y": 59
            },
            {
              "x": 212,
              "y": 59
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I need a way to get the possible date with day, month, and year in order to create a js date.
The problem is that sometimes the month is written with 3 letters (eg. "APR" for "april"), or the year is missing, or the year comes at the end of the date instead of the start, any format really.

I'm open to any kind of help (libraries, custom functions, machine learning API), as the date is so inconsistent that is really becoming a pain trying to make it understand the current format of the scanned date.
Also, let's try make it work by saying that the current language is EN-US. I'll figure out later how to handle languages

Comment: Is it always between \n ... \n in this sentence `"description": "Da consumarsi preferibilmente entro:\n15 04 11\n",` ?

Comment: Also will you get sued if you get it wrong and ppl eat something from 2012 instead of 20th of December?

Comment: Usually yes, but sometimes month and year don't have a space in between so it doesn't really figure it out.
Not to worry, it's just an early idea/prototype, far from actual public usage